# Rsyslog imudp splits message containing colon

Tags: json, rsyslog

We're having trouble sending messages to rsyslog via imudp. Our message contains a colon (":") but imudp seems to be using it as delimiter.

Can we disable the delimiting so the entire message is read into a single field?

In case this is not because of imudp, can someone point out where the actual problem is? Is there a problem with the template construction?

**INPUT**
`echo "deploys.test.myservice:4|c" | nc -w0 -u localhost 12345`

**RSYSLOG TEMPLATE**
`template(name="json_lines" type="list" option.json="on") {
  constant(value="{ \"timestamp\":\"")
  property(name="timestamp" dateFormat="rfc3339")
  constant(value="\",\"message\":\"")
  property(name="msg")
  constant(value="\",\"host\":\"")
  property(name="hostname")
  constant(value="\",\"type\":\"")
  property(name="syslogtag")
  constant(value="\"}")
}`

**OUTPUT**
`{
    "timestamp":"2016-11-22T16:15:15.773754+05:30",
    "message":"4|c",
    "host":"localhost",
    "type":"deploys.test.myservice:"
}`

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

*Disclaimer: I'm still actively learning the ins/outs of rsyslog*

Have a look at the [pmnull module](http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/configuration/modules/pmnull.html) if you want to accept raw messages without any processing.

Example from the [documentation](http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/configuration/modules/pmnull.html):

```
module(load="imtcp")
module(load="pmnull")

input(type="imtcp" port="13514" ruleset="ruleset")
parser(name="custom.pmnull" type="pmnull")

ruleset(name="ruleset" parser="custom.pmnull") {
      action(type="omfile" file="rsyslog.out.log")
}
```

Presumably you could setup a UDP input the same way as the TCP input shown here.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, @deoren, looks like it would do what I want, but at this point I can't check it since it's been too long and I don't have the setup handy. Will give this a shot as soon as I find a free weekend.

Comment: You're welcome. If you run into problems implementing the changes, the [mailing list](http://lists.adiscon.net/mailman/listinfo/rsyslog) and [forums](http://kb.monitorware.com/rsyslog-f40.html) are good resources as well as the StackExchange sites here.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use "rawmsg" instead of "msg" in your template. This is a simpler path to try.

I could not use "pmnull" option because rsyslog failed with the following error ([more info](https://github.com/rsyslog/rsyslog/issues/2799)):

> rsyslogd: could not load module '/usr/lib64/rsyslog/pmnull.so', dlopen: /usr/lib64/rsyslog/pmnull.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory  [v8.36.0 try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2066 ]